# Deducing Multiples of Two Numbers

Tags: number-theory

First Question: If I know a positive integer $n=7k$ (multiple of 7) and $m=5q$ (mutliple of 5) is there any way to deduce what multiples the sum of $n+m$ must produce? Or maybe exclude multiples that we can be for sure will not be divisible by the sum?

There has to be a way!! There has to be at least a way to exclude certain divisors.

Second question: if $n$ has 6 factors and $m$ has 4 factors, can I deduce anything about the number of factors the sum will have?

Comment: For starters, unless $q$ is a multiple of $7$, $n+m$ is NOT a multiple of $7$.  Your second question is related to the famous [abc conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture), which may have been solved recently.

Answer (score 2):

No, by the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) the sum $n+m$ can have any remainder when divided by any number you choose, because $5$ and $7$ are coprime.  For example, if you ask that $n+m \equiv 13 \pmod {29}$ we just need to solve the three congruences $$x\equiv 0 \pmod 5\\x \equiv 0 \pmod 7\\x \equiv 13 \pmod {29}$$ which the CRT guarantees we can, and having found one, we can add any multiple of $5\cdot 7 \cdot 29$ and get another one.  Why does there have to be a way?